# How to obtain the dimension of the domain of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given a general function $f(x,y):R^2\rightarrow R$, the dimension of the domain is $(x,y)\in R^2$. The dimension means that if the value of $f(x,y)$ relies on both $(x,y)$, it has dimension of two for the domain. If the value of $f(x,y)$ only relies on $x$ or $y$, it has dimension of one for the domain.

For some special function, we may have $f_1(x,y)=g(x)$, which only depends on the variable $x$ and becomes a one-variable function.

For another function $f_2(x,y)$, when it can not be reduced to a one-dimensional function, it is impossible $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y), \forall x,y$. Thus, the necessary condition for $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ is that they should be reduced to the same dimension.

My question is when we do not have explicit expression of $f(x,y)$, how can we obtain the effective dimension of its domain? For example, how can we determine whether it relies on $x,y$ or just a constant function.

Comment: What sort of definition for $f(x,y)$ do you have in mind, if not an explicit expression?

Comment: For some $f(x,y)$, its value can be given by a complex optimization problem. We can not easily obtain the solution or explicit expression at a glance.

Comment: I think the answer will depend a lot on how your function is represented. E.g. if you can determine that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=0$ everywhere, then $f$ does not depend on $y$.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure "dimension of the domain" is a good name for this - I'd expect a notion of dimension to be invariant under a linear change of coordinates (like a rotation), but your property seems to depend on the coordinate directions.